# Highcharts Column w/ drilldown not working in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

Ruby 2.1, Rails 4, using Highcharts to build a column chart with drilldown. Locally, when I click on the chart and try to get it to show me the drilldown functionality, it doesn't work, but when I copy the code over the JSFiddle, it appears to work great. I've checked to see if there is maybe something preventing the event handlers from being called, but upon clicking one of the SVG elements on the highchart with a jQuery event handler I wrote, this appears to work fine as well.

I could provide a copy sample, but it works great on JSFiddle, so I don't think it would be helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your sample.

Comment: So how we can replicate your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the problem!

In Rails, in your JavaScript manifest file (`application.js`), make sure to include the drilldown module:

```
//= require highcharts/modules/drilldown
```

Outside of Rails, looks like you can include the drilldown module as a script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```